# RSpec how to stub out yield and have it not hit ensure

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec, rspec-rails

I have an around action_action called `set_current_user`

```
def set_current_user
  CurrentUser.set(current_user) do
    yield
  end
end
```

In the CurrentUser singleton

```
  def set(user)
    self.user = user
    yield
  ensure
    self.user = nil
  end
```

I cannot figure out how to stub out the yield and the not have the ensure part of the method called

Ideally I would like to do something like

```
it 'sets the user' do
  subject.set(user)
  expect(subject.user).to eql user
end
```

Two errors I am getting

- 1. No block is given
- 2. When I do pass a block `self.user = nil` gets called

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `block_given?` method can be used inside your method to tell whether a block has been supplied. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you intend to accomplish with this as it appears you just want to make sure that `user` is set in the block and unset afterwards. If this is the case then the following should work fine

```
class CurrentUser
  attr_accessor :user
  def set(user)
    self.user = user
    yield
  ensure
    self.user = nil
  end
end

describe '.set' do
  subject { CurrentUser.new }
  let(:user) { OpenStruct.new(id: 1) }
  it 'sets user for the block only' do 
    subject.set(user) do 
      expect(subject.user).to eq(user)
    end 
    expect(subject.user).to be_nil 
  end
end
```

This will check that inside the block (where yield is called) that `subject.user` is equal to `user` and that afterwards `subject.user` is nil.

**Output**:

```
.set
  sets user for the block only

Finished in 0.03504 seconds (files took 0.14009 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things to point out that might help:

`ensure` is reserved for block of codes that you want to run no matter what happens, hence the reason why your `self.user` will always be `nil`. I think what you want is to assign user to nil if there's an exception. In this case, you should be using `rescue` instead.

```
def set(user)
  self.user = user
  yield
rescue => e
  self.user = nil
end
```

As for the unit test, what you want is to be testing only the `.set` method in the `CurrentUser` class. Assuming you have everything hooked up correctly in your around filter, here's a sample that might work for you:

```
describe CurrentUser do
  describe '.set' do
    let(:current_user) { create(:user) } 
    subject do
      CurrentUser.set(current_user) {}
    end
    it 'sets the user' do
      subject
      expect(CurrentUser.user).to eq(current_user)
    end 
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your response I failed to mention that I need to clear out the user after every request. I posted an answer below, which I admit is kinda weird but does get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

I failed to mention I need to clear out the user after every request.

This is what I came up with. Its kinda crazy to put the expectation inside of the lambda but does ensure the user is set prior to the request being processed and clears it after

```
describe '.set' do
  subject { described_class }

  let(:user) { OpenStruct.new(id: 1) }

  let(:user_expectation) { lambda{ expect(subject.user).to eql user } }

  it 'sets the user prior to the block being processed' do
    subject.set(user) { user_expectation.call }
  end

  context 'after the block has been processed' do
    # This makes sure the user is always cleared after a request
    # even if there is an error and sidekiq will never have access to it.

    before do
      subject.set(user) { lambda{} }
    end

    it 'clears out the user' do
      expect(subject.user).to eql nil
    end
  end
end
```